# Check if string contains all unique characters

Tags: java, string, algorithm

//  O(N) - without additional data structure...

```
private boolean isUniqueWithoutDS(String str){
    boolean value = true;

    int checker = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int c = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        System.out.println("checker is : " + checker);
        System.out.println("1<<c is " + (1<<c));   
        if((checker & (1 << c))>0){
            value = false;
            break;
        }
        checker = checker | 1<<c;
    }

    return value;
}
```

This is my code and works fine, I am not able to understand how it works for capital and small letters combined string. For example "`Zizu`" it works. For all small lettered string it works and I know how it works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer might depend on language, but in Java (JLS [15.19. Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x1f` (`0b11111`). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range `0` to `31`, inclusive.

So it is like you execute `c = c & 0x1f`, or `c = c % 32`, so both uppercase `A` and lower-case `a` becomes `c` value of `0`, for the purpose of the `<<` operator.

I'd assume that other languages may work similarly, for a 32-bit `int` type.

Comment: So, it works for capital and small case letters in same way? Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

another way to check if the string contains all unique character or not  --  in **O(N)**:

1. use an infinite loop
2. use two-variable i (i=0) and j=(n-1 [where n-is string length])
3. check every i-th char is equal to j-th char or not

   3.1 if [i-th char == j-th && i != j char], break the loop cause string contain duplicate chars. (i != j denotes comparing with same char)

   3.2 decrement j and set j to n-1 and i += 1, when j = 0 [this part is tricky]
4. repeat step 3 unless i becomes n-1th size

**CODE**

```
    String s = "abcde";

    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length()-1;

    boolean flag = true;

    while(true) {
        if(i == s.length()-1)
            break;
        // DUPLICATE FOUND
        if(i != j && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }else {
            j--;
            // COMPARING DONE AGAINST i-TH CHAR TO ALL OTHER CHARS, INCREMENT i NOW
            if(j == 0) {
                j = s.length()-1;
                i += 1;
            }
        }           
    }

    if(flag)
        System.out.println("unique");
    else
        System.out.println("non-unique");
```

Comment: the code here is O(N^2). It simulates a double for loop like "for (i = 0; i < n; i++) for (j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)" using a single while, but the amount of processing is the same.

Comment: waiting for someone to oppose me! yeah you're right. it is nothing but expanding O(n^2) to O(n) :D but the solution is in O(n) :P

Comment: :) you are right, because there are only O(1) characters in the alphabet (so it can't take long until the infinite loop breaks) - upvoted.

Comment: It is still an _O(n^2)_ style algorithm, a rewrite of a double loop like qwertyman said, which simply tries to obfuscate the double loop nature of the algorithm. Sure, if input is limited to letters only, the complexity is capped, but performance is still way slower than question code. If input is not limited to letters (question code implies it is, but question doesn't stipulate that), then performance gets even worse. Of course, question code fails in that case, so a better solution is needed, but this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an array of size 256 to store a count for each character (assuming there are 256 possible characters) which is set to value 0 at the start of your loop. Then, just simply increment each position when you fetch each next character. Finally, there is a quick hack that checks if the value in the position is 0 or 1 (e.g., `freq[i] == !!freq[i])`. This if statement `[freq[i] == !!freq[i]]` is the one that should hold for all 256 items in the array.

UPDATED:

```
unsigned int isDistinctStr(char *str);
unsigned int isDistinctStr(char *str) {
    unsigned int ct, freq[256], i, j;
    char ch;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {freq[i] = 0;}
    for (ct = 0; ch = *str; str++) {
        j = (unsigned int) (ch & 0xffu);
        freq[j]++;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        if (freq[j] == !!freq[j]) {ct++;}
    }
    return (ct == 256) ? 1 : 0;
}
```